# PHP if else statements error check

Tags: php, html

**I am editing this to clarify my question. users input a membername and displayname in a form, and the php looks for the membername in a list to match against, then edits the display name when successfully finding it with the user's input.**

membernames and usernames are stored in the file like:

```
membername=displayname
```

**This code works, except if they mistype their membername (meaning it doesn't match what is in the file), *it still redirects to the success page*, however it does not change the file (as it shouldn't).**

What I need is to display an error page when they type in a membername that does not match, however I cannot get it to work.

```
<?
$fileurl = '/../../.../..../memberfiletest';

$membername = $_POST['membername'];
$displayname = $_POST['displayname']; 

$file = file($fileurl, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); // Get file as array of lines

foreach ($file as $n => $line) {
$parts = explode('=', $line);
if ($parts[0] == $membername) {
    $file[$n] = $membername . '=' . $displayname;
}
}
file_put_contents($fileurl, implode("\n", $file)); // Put file back together
$success_page = 'http://example.com/.../private.php';
header('Location: '.$success_page);
?>
```

**edited coding that I've tried** : Using this coding below I've attempted to use it as is and modifying it. If I put in an error page to use a redirect it goes to the error page whether the script runs or not. On successful change it never redirects to google (using google just as a test).

```
<?
$fileurl = '/.../..../...../...../memberfiletest';

$membername = $_POST['membername'];
$displayname = $_POST['displayname']; 

$file = file($fileurl, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); // Get file as array of lines

foreach ($file as $n => $line) {

$parts = explode('=', $line);
if ($parts[0] == $membername) {

    $file[$n] = $membername . '=' . $displayname;
    //write the contents and redirect here itself
    file_put_contents($fileurl, implode("\n", $file));
    $success_page = 'http://google.com';//simply redirecting to google if its true
    header('Location: '.$success_page);
} 
else {//throw an error
    //use this 
    $flag = 1;
}

if(isset($flag)){
    //die("Membername not found");
    header('Location:'.$error_page);
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change from this

```
if ($parts[0] == $membername) {
    die("Membername not found");
} 
else {
    $file[$n] = $membername . '=' . $displayname;
}
```

to this

```
//when you match you put in array
if ($parts[0] == $membername) {
    $file[$n] = $membername . '=' . $displayname;
    //soon after you got a match put the contents in file and redirect
} 
else {//throw an error
    //die("Membername not found");
    //use this 
    $flag = 1;
}

if(isset($flag)){
   //do what you need to handle the error
}
```

Edit2: Try this [link](http://pastie.org/10742067).

Comment: Oddly enough when I did that, it just kills the script and displays an error page that says "Membername not found" even though I know I entered in a correct membername.

Comment: thank you narasimharaosp for the edits. I have it in there and I updated my coding in my original post so you can see how I put the flag coding to handle the error, am not sure if its correct, it still simply dies and shows the page "membername not found" no matter what i input.

Comment: Thank you for the edited link. When I do that, it goes through and works, however does not redirect to google, and if I use a bogus membername it doesn't redirect it just hangs on a white page which is the .php page its going to and doesn't make the changes on the backend in the file. So there's no re-direct and no real error page.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($file as $n => $line) {

$parts = explode('=', $line);

if($parts[0] == $membername) {
    $file[$n] = $membername . '=' . $displayname;
    //write the contents and redirect here itself
    file_put_contents($fileurl, implode("\r\n", $file));
    $page = 'http://google.com';//simply redirecting to google if its true
} 
else {//throw an error
   //use this 
   $page = $err_page;
}

header('Location:'.$page);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Bhavik when I tried your code it came up and said invalid argument on line 7 foreach () I didn't change anything else so I'm unsure why that is I'm doublechecking my code.

Comment: I tried it again inputting your code directly and the only thing I changed was the $err_page to go someplace else so I could tell if it errored, and in both cases, it SKIPS the first redirect and whether on success or fail, it goes to whatever error page I input.

Comment: i used the same code and executed it. and it was not showing any error and running successfully. I used text file to store and retrieve the data.

Comment: It runs and executes the script, the problem seems to be that it runs all the way through the redirect page regardless of if wrong data is input or not. When a person inputs their membername and displayname, its supposed to find the membername and if so, then change the line it needs to. It does this correctly, however if a wrong membername is put in, it still goes through to the re-direct page,

Comment: however it does not make the changes in the file but it doesn't show an error page either. hopefully that makes sense. I need it to show an error if the membername they put in, does not match what is in the file.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally resolve this by studying $flags more and ensuring that I had them written properly and in the correct context for when I wanted the checks to apply.

```
 <?
$fileurl = '/..../..../..../..../memberfiletest';

$membername = $_POST['membername'];
$displayname = $_POST['displayname'];

$file = file($fileurl, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); // Get file as array of lines
$found = 0;

foreach ($file as $n => $line) 
{

$parts = explode('=', $line);
if ($parts[0] == $membername) 
{

    $file[$n] = $membername . '=' . $displayname;
    // write the contents and redirect here itself
    file_put_contents($fileurl, implode("\n", $file));
    $success_page = 'http://.../..../...html'; // redirect
                                                                                // if
                                                                                // successful
    header('Location: ' . $success_page);
    $found = 1;
}
}

if ($found == 0)
{
// No matching user... Redirect to error     
$error_page = 'http://google.com'; // redirecting to google just for
                                       // testing
header('Location:' . $error_page);
}
?>
```